# If product space of two spaces is normal, then are the two spaces normal?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

> We know that product of **normal** spaces need not be **normal**,for e.g. ${R_{l}}^2$. My question is regarding the converse.   If $X$ & $Y$ are two spaces such that $X \times Y$ is **normal**, then can we claim that $X$ & $Y$ are **normal** spaces? In case of **regular**, **hausdorff** or **T-1** spaces, this appear to be true and can be proven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A,A'$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$, then $A\times Y$, $A'\times Y$ are disjoint closed of $X\times Y$. Accordingly, let $O$, $O'$ be open neighbourhoods. Write $O=\bigcup _i U_i\times V_i$, $O'=\bigcup _j U'_j\times V'_j$ where each $U_i, U'_j$ is open in $X$ and $V_i, V'_j$ is open in $Y$.
Pick $y\in Y$. Then 
$$ \bigcup \{\, U_i\mid y\in V_i\,\},\quad \bigcup \{\, U'_j\mid y\in V'_j\,\}$$
are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $A$ and $A'$.

Comment: How can we be sure that the open set you have defined will definitely contain A. Some points of $A \times Y$ may lie in those $U_i \times V_i$ for which $y \notin V_i$

Comment: @LordKK $A \times \{y\}$ is covered by those $U_i \times V_i$ with $y \in V_i$.

Comment: I mean to say, there may be some $a \times z$ such that $a \notin V_i$ for all such $y \in V_i $

Comment: @LordKK $$A \times \{y\} \subset A \times Y \subset \bigcup (U_i \times V_i)$$ Since $U_j \times V_j \cap A \times \{y\} = \varnothing$ if $y \notin V_j$, it follows that $$A \times \{y\} \subset \bigcup \{ U_i \times V_i : y \in V_i\}\,.$$ Of course this needs the existence of some $y\in Y$, if either factor is empty, the product is empty and hence normal regardless of what properties the other factor has.

Answer (score 2):

We will only consider the case that $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty; otherwise $X \times Y = \emptyset$ is normal, but we can make no statement about $X$ (if $Y = \emptyset$) or $Y$ (if $X = \emptyset$).
If we assume that $X, Y \neq \emptyset$, then the statement is true:

Recall that a topological space $X$ is normal if and only if the Tietze extension theorem holds for $X$, i.e. if for every closed subset $A \subseteq X$, every continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a continuous function $F \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $X \times Y$ is normal, let $A \subseteq X$ be a closed set and let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
Let $p \colon X \times Y \to X$ be the projection onto the first coordinate.
Then
$$
      B
  :=  p^{-1}(A)
   =  A \times Y
$$
is a closed subset of $X \times Y$.
Define $g \colon B \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g := f \circ p|_B$, i.e. by $g(a,y) = f(a)$ for all $(a,y) \in B$.
Then $g$ is continuous, and can thus be extended to a continuous function $G \colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$.
Let $y_0 \in Y$ and consider the map
$$
          F
  \colon  X
  \to     \mathbb{R},
  \quad   x
  \mapsto G(x,y_0).
$$
Then $F$ is a continuous extension of $f$.

This shows that $X$ is normal, if $Y$ is non-empty.
If both $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty, then it follows that they are both normal.

Comment: If you assume $T_1$, this is overkill. In that case $X \simeq X \times \{y\}$, where $y \in Y$ is arbitrary and the latter is normal as a closed (by $T_1$) subset of $X \times Y$. Etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: You’re right, I removed the assumption.

Comment: But then Tietze no longer holds..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Tietze's extension theorem is equivalent to the lesser of $T_4$ and normal, it doesn't need $T_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer maybe ( Engelking proves it with $T_1$, is there a well known source for your claim?), but then I still think it’s shooting a midge with a cannon.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Don't know about well-known, But Boto v. Querenburg, _Mengentheoretische Topologie_, Satz 7.7. (Note that they use the  convention that "normal $= T_4 + T_1$", so the statement says $X$ is a $T_4$ space if and only if … .)

Comment: I reread the proof in Bredon’s _Topology and Geometry_, and if I’m not mistaken it only uses Urysohn’s Lemma, which does not seem to need $T_1$. This also matches with [Wikipedia’s claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem#Equivalent_statements) that Tietze’s Theorem is equivalent to Urysohn’s Lemma.

Comment: @DanielFischer I concur that $T_1$ is not needed. I checked Boto, one of just 4 of my German topology books. Hagen’s answer is simpler though.