Singletons in regular spaces
I need help with a statement.
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be topological spaces and consider $X = X_1 \times X_2$. Suppose the product space $X$ is regular, that is, for any closed subset $C \subset X$ and any point $p \in X$, there exist disjoint open subsets $U, V \subset X$ such that $p \in U$ and $C \subset V$.
Fix $q \in X_2$ and consider the subspace $X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace \subset X$. Now consider a closed subset $D \subset (X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace)$. For $D$ to be closed in $X$, it is necessary and sufficient that there exists a closed subset $F \subset X$ such that $D = F \cap (X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace)$. But this will only be true when $X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace$ is closed in $X$.

Is there any way to ensure that $X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace$ is closed in $X$?

I know that, since $(X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace) \subset X_1 \times X_2$, then $(X_1 \times X_2) \setminus (X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace) = (X_2 \setminus \lbrace q\rbrace) \times X_1$, but I can't advance from there.
Thank you for your help.
EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------------
I need to prove that $X_1$ is regular. For this, let $F_1 \subset X_1$ be closed, $p \in X_1 \setminus F$ and $q \in X_2$ fixed. The map $h\colon X_1 \longrightarrow X_1 \times X_2$ given by $h(x) = (x,q)$ is a homeomorphism between $X_1$ and $X_1 \times \lbrace q\rbrace$ (I have already proved this fact previously, and it is clear to me).
Therefore, it is clear that $h(F_1) = \lbrace (x,q) \in X ; x \in F_1 \rbrace$ is closed in $X_1 \times \lbrace q \rbrace$. But I need $h(F_1)$ to be closed in $X$. Ok, let's assume this is true.
Since $h(F_1)$ is closed in $X$, and $X$ is regular, there exist disjoint open sets $U, V \subset X$ such that $h(F_1) \subset U$ and $(p,q) \in V$.
The inverse of the map $h$ is the restriction of the projection $\pi|_{X_1\times\lbrace q\rbrace}$, where $\pi|_{X_1 \times \lbrace q \rbrace}(U)$ and $\pi|_{X_1 \times \lbrace q \rbrace}(V)$ are disjoint open sets in $X_1$ that contain $F_1$ and $p$, respectively.
I couldn't visualize another argument besides this one. But in order to this argument work, I need $h(F_1)$ to be closed in $X$, which means there must exist a closed subset $C \subset X$ such that $h(F_1) = C \cap X_1 \times \lbrace q \rbrace$. And this is what is making me stuck.

If $X_2$ is $T_1$, then $X_1 \times {q}$ is closed. Otherwise it might not be. (You don’t need this statement to prove $X_1$ is regular, though. If that’s your motivation for this question.)

@DavidGao Yes, I need to prove that $X_1$ is regular. I edited my post and included the arguments I am using. Please take a look.

I'll first show that $X_1 \times \{q\}$ needs not be closed. For example, let $X_2 = \{p, q\}$ with the trivial topology. $X_1$ can be whatever (nonempty) regular space you want. Then $X_1 \times X_2$ is regular (of course, not Hausdorff regular, but still regular per the definition you're using). But $X_1 \times \{q\}$ is not closed. In fact, its closure is the entirety of $X_1 \times X_2$. (An additional comment: of course, if $X_2$ is $T_1$, then $\{q\} \subset X_2$ is closed, so $X_1 \times \{q\}$ is closed in $X_1 \times X_2$. In fact, what you are asking is literally just equivalent to $\{q\} \subset X_2$ being closed.)
Now, having said that, in order to prove $X_1$ is regular, you don't need to do this. Since you already know that $X_1$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $X_1 \times X_2$ (namely $X_1 \times \{q\}$), I'll just show that any subspace of a regular space is regular. Let $Y \subset X$ where $X$ is regular. Let $C \subset Y$ be closed in the subspace topology, $x \in Y \setminus C$. By definition of subspace topology, there exists $K \subset X$ closed s.t. $C = K \cap Y$. But then $x \notin K$. Indeed, if $x \in K$, then as $x \in Y$, we would have $x \in K \cap Y = C$, a contradiction. Thus, by regularity of $X$, there exists $U, V \subset X$ disjoint open sets with $K \subset U$ and $x \in V$. But then $C \subset U \cap Y$, $x \in V \cap Y$, and $U \cap Y$, $V \cap Y$ are disjoint subsets of $Y$ that are open in the subspace topology on $Y$. This shows $Y$ is regular.

Of course! And since regularity is a topological property (it is right?) we can conclude the proof. Is that right?

@JoelMarques Yes, regularity is (practically by definition) preserved by homeomorphisms.

Thanks for your help!

Can a similar argument be used to show that $X_1$ is normal when $X$ is normal?

@JoelMarques It’s not true that a subspace of normal space must be normal (see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank), so this argument cannot work as is. (The reason it breaks down is because the two closed sets of the larger space may no longer be disjoint.)

@JoelMarques Then again, a closed subspace of a normal space is actually normal, so if we are talking about $T_1$ normal spaces, then this argument works fine. For a proof of the general case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2815086/465145

Thanks again for your help.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
